What is the difference between these separation theorems?

Theorem 1: Let $A$ and $B$ be convex sets of real normed $X$. If $A$ is compact in $X$ and $B$ is closed, then there is $f\in X^*$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\leq\lambda_1<\lambda_2\leq f(y)$ for all $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.


Theorem 2: Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint, nonempty, convex sets of normed $X$ such that $A$ is compact in $X$ and $B$ is closed, then there is $f\in X^*$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>\lambda$ for all $x\in A$ and $f(y)<\lambda$ for all $y\in B$.


Theorem 3: Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint, nonempty, convex sets in a topological linear space $X$ . If $A$ is open in $X$ , then there is $f\in X^*$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)<\lambda\leq f(y)$ for all $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.


Theorem 4: Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint, nonempty, convex sets in a locally convex $X$. If $A$ is compact in $X$ and $B$ is closed, then there is $f\in X^*$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)<\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq f(y)$ for all $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.

In my professor's lecture notes, we have the above for theorems. I have few question:

Theorem 2 seems to imply that $f(y)<\lambda<f(x)$, but this is the opposite to Theorem 1.
But, then theorem 4 seems the same to Theorem 2, but $f(x)<\lambda_1$ is changed to $f(x)\leq\lambda_1$. Why is this?
Is there a reason/intuition behind the order/direction of these inequalities?


$f(y)<\lambda<f(x)$ becomes $f(x)<\lambda<f(y)$ if you change $f$ to $-f$ and $\lambda$ to $-\lambda$. You cannot get strict inequalities under the hypothesis of Theorem 3.

@geetha290krm, could you elaborate more please
